# querySelector(".class").remove() goes very slow on iphone but not so much on android, what could it be?

Tags: javascript, performance, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I've made a design portfolio, basically the whole website is just one page and for each project, there's a div that pops out and show the content (images and embedded Vimeo videos)

What I've noticed is that when closing a project on mobile (either using 'x' button or opening another project) it takes very very long (about 2/4 seconds) on iphone 8 while on an older android phone it takes less, even though with the andorid it's overall bit more laggy.

[this is the website](https://aieio.github.io/)

I've also checked on [google page speed insight](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Faieio.github.io%2F) but I couldn't figure out why on iphone is slower than desktop or android mobile.

Can you please help me understand what could I do to trying speeding up the website? Do you have any advice about what to check or tests to run? I know I haven't provided a short code example and I apologize if this kind of question are not accepted, in that case I'll remove the post

Thank you very much!